# Updating document with id from other action using previous id (nodejs & mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have something I cant find a solution for …
Let me explain in in short:
Step 1. Create a new collection in document A
Step 2. Use this id and create a new collection in document B
Step 3. Update collection from step 1 with the id from step2

In nodejs:

```
DocumentA.create({something})
.then((result)=>{
DocumentB.create({x : result.id})})
.then((result2) => { 
DocumentA.updateOne({_id: ?????}, {$set:{y: result2.id}})
```

And completely stuck here (at the ????) as I cannot use ‘result’ anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage switching to using `async/await` but you can do something like this:

```
DocumentA.create({something})
.then((result)=>{
   return Promise.All([
     Promise.resolve(result), 
     DocumentB.create({x : result.id})
   ])
.then(([result, result2]) => { 
  DocumentA.updateOne({_id: result._id, {$set:{y: result2.id}
})
```

The primary thing is to use `return <Promise>` to pass to the next `.then`

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you so much. I already had a deep look into resolving promises but thanks to you, i finally understand it!